# How do I access Google API methods that include siteURL with the ruby client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to access the Google Webmaster Tools API with the ruby client:

```
webmaster_tools_api = client.discovered_api('webmasters', 'v3') 

                  result = client.execute(
                    :api_method  => webmaster_tools_api.sites.example.com.urlCrawlErrorsCounts.query,

                   )
```

The API method I am trying to access uses the siteurl in the method name. This won't work because the syntax conflicts.

Is there a way to access API method names that include URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results = client.execute(
  api_method: webmaster_tools_api.urlcrawlerrorscounts.query,
  parameters: { 'siteUrl' => 'example.com' }
)
```

(Google's API docs are terrible so it's not surprising you couldn't find this.)

Comment: Agreed. The docs are awful. Any suggestions for better sources of information or will I have to read their source code?